# I want one choice to effect two fields in admin

Tags: django, subclassing, mezzanine

I am subclassing a model from Mezzanine, a django app.

In the admin, I want to have a choice list.  The choice is tied to an image from a fixed list of images which will be displayed in a blog post.

So, the admin would have a nice little thumbnail next to the choice after choosing from the list.

I have looked into subclassing or extending a django field, but this is above my head (not totally.)

`FileBrowseField` is the closest fit I've found.

I would consider any path offered. I like a challenge and I have the time.  I'm not looking to have the blog writer upload an image, but the images are with the choices already.

Again, I would like to include the image in the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to require knowledge of Javascript as well as Django's admin system and template language. The core components are a custom admin.py for your custom model.py, an admin widget for choosing your image, and template changes for both the end-user and admin interface. A static list of images can be included as [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) on a [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#charfield). If the value of the `choices` key-value pair is a url to an image, you can then write a thumbnail of that to your template.

Alternatively, you could create an Image model that has a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) relation to your blog post (or vice versa, depending on your goal) and use the FileBrowseField as a field on that Image.